# Dart - Split content of HTML tags

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

So I got this regex which matches everything inside an HTML tag:

```
/(?<=<\s*\w+[^>]*>)(.*)(?=<\/\w+>)/gm
```

Playground: https://regex101.com/r/WthKUd/3

What the regex does:

- `(?<=<\s*\w+[^>]*>)` Checks for opening HTML tag
- `(.*)` - Checks for any character
- `(?=<\/\w+>)` - Checks for closing HTML tag

Now I need to tweak this so that I can extract content from a tag as a `List`.

So given the string:

```
<p>Lazy fox has <b>text</b> and <b>bold text again</b></p>
```

And doing:

```
<pattern>.allMatches('<p>Lazy fox has <b>text</b> and <b>bold text again</b></p>');
```

The result would be:

```
[
  'Lazy fox has ',
  '<b>text</b>',
  ' and ',
  '<b>bold text again</b>'
]
```

It should basically split normal text content from HTML tags so I can populate a `RichText` widget with the correct styles.

I have tried to modify the regex in quite a few ways but I can't seem to get it to match text as one match group and tags as another.

How would I tweak the regex to do what I want?

**EDIT:** I am well aware of existing parsers and we are already using flutter_html but it doesn't meet some of our needs which is why I'm creating a simpler, slimmed down version.

Comment: I think the question is well asked, but do you really want to use a regex? Perhaps it might be better to use a parser?

Comment: Parsing HTML with RegEx is just making a bigger mess out of an already messy affair. Look for a decent HTML parser, don't hand craft a duct tape solution.

Comment: HTML is nested scope, like parens in a math expression.  Difficult (but not impossible) to match with regex.  Take advice of others here posting already... abandon regex for this.

Comment: We already use the flutter_html package, but it doesn't suit our needs which is why we are forced to create our own, slimmed down version of a parser. Hope this clears up why I'm doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It's may not be the solution that you are searching for, but I used the [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) package for a while now, and the render is great, maybe you can switch your RichText widget to this dependency ?

With this dependency, you can choose to only render some html tags and remove some others.

Comment: That is not what I need, I have already checked it out.